# Defining a new instance attribute dynamically in Python

Tags: python

Why is it possible to dynamically define a new attribute for every class instance in Python as long as it's not of type `object`?

```
class NewStyle(object):
    pass

class OldStyle:
    pass

a = object()
# This line raises AttributeError
a.foo = 1

# All of these work fine
a = Exception()
a.foo = 1

a = OldStyle()
a.foo = 1

a = NewStyle()
a.foo = 1
```

This behaviour seems to be identical in Python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object):

> Note: `object` does not have a `__dict__`, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the `object` class.

Some class definition provide a `__dict__` attribute and then it is included in instances by default.

See also [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Comment: Where does the default implementation of __dict__ come from, if not from `object`?